# Visualize and analyze data from Kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana, confluent-platform

I am using a basic Kafka-Logstash setup to sync many different applications with the backend. I have a very basic understanding about how this works. Currently I am looking into analyzing the data processed by Kafka. I want to use Kafka Connect to get everything on a Kibana board and I am very unsure on how to tackle this.

I found [this resource](https://www.confluent.io/blog/the-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/) which says the following:

> Whilst Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka itself, if you want to stream data from Kafka to Elasticsearch you’ll want the Confluent Platform.

My questions are:

**1. Do I have to use Confluent to achieve that?**

**2. Should I use Confluent to achieve that?**

I also looked into other tools like for example [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus) but as far as I could see it is not easily possible to achieve Kibana-like visualization. But please educate me if I am wrong!

Comment: Prometheus has a connector for Kafka. I think it's geared towards technical details i.e. how much memory your broker is using https://grafana.com/dashboards/7589. Also checkout management console section at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Ecosystem. I am also new at this so I don't have specific answer.

Comment: Confluent has open-sourced few of the common Connectors. You don't have to use them. But I would recommend you to try kafka related connector; if it does what you want then use it otherwise you can write your own connector.

Comment: Not clear what you mean "use Confluent". Confluent has open-sourced all the components you would be using here... Kafka Connect is not specific to Confluent. Really, just the schema registry, which can be added to any Kafka cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used both Logstash (with JSON data over tcp input plugin) and Kafka Connect Elastic connector by Confluent (with Avro data), both with just regular Apache Kafka. So, the answer to **do you**, no. It will just take more time to configure Kafka Connect, since you'll have to build the source code, so **should you**, sure, because it's still the same Apache Kafka at the end of the day.

Both will work with Kibana, but this of course largley depends on how you manage index patterns in Elasticsearch and what data you are ingesting.

Personally I find Logstash a bit simpler if you know nothing about setting up Elasticsearch indicies and type mappings because Logstash's Elasticsearch output plugin "just works". I can't recall if I used the Kafka input plugin, but I would imagine it works similarly to any other inputs, but there may be problems around the Kafka deserializers if you have some non-standard serialization from your producers (for example, some people put Protobuf data into Kafka)

I see Prometheus/Grafana more for metrics, not visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize and analyse kafka data using Logstash Kafka input plugin. Below is the sample Logstash snippet configuration.

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    client_id => "client_id_name"  // optional 
    topics => ["topic_name"]
  }

}

//Logstash provides different filters like json,csv and etc..You can add filters based on your requirements. 

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
        index => "index_name"
        document_type => "document_type_name"  // optional 
    }
}
```

Please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html for more kafka input configurations option